# Is there a System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.PostAsync()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I can return anything back to the UI thread like this:

```
// when I am on the UI thread
var _UI = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
// then on a background thread
_UI.Post((x) => { DoSomething(); }, null);
```

But, if I am on that background thread for to make it **asynchrnous**, then calling _UI.Post() will undo my efforts and **makes the UI wait** for the execution of DoSomething().

Of course _UI.PostAsync() is pseudo-code. But **is there a way to execute on the UI thread but in an asynchronous way**? Fundamentally, I realize I am exposing my lack of knowlege and understanding. Be merciful, please. I'm just asking ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SynchronizationContext.Post()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) will not block the background thread, as it asynchronously "posts" back to the UI thread (in this case).

The UI thread will only block for the duration of the `DoSomething()` call - but in this case, you're saying you *must run that on the UI thread*, in which case, it will tie up the UI thread.

The key here is to put most of your work on the background thread, and only call `.Post(...)` for operations that directly set the user interface.  As such, they should be very fast operations, and never (noticably) block the UI.

Comment: I think I have to take that as a "no", huh? I get what you are saying, just was hoping for some type of secret trick. When the Post is updating an ObservableCollection bound to something, it's a bummer.

Comment: @Jerry: Post is the asynchronous method - but it's asynchronous on the thread which its called (the BG thread).  If you're trying to update an OC, the *update* has to happen on the UI thread, but not the work involved in generating the collection.  Build the collection (into a `List<T>`), and Post the `List<T>` back to the UI thread, and use it to initialize the OC (which will be very fast).

Comment: Ten4, thanks again. The best is to break it apart. Sometimes more code is just better. Strange to say, but true. C#5 will make Async so much more "readable"; looking forward to it.